# Wave equation derivation in a transmission line

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

[image]

$$
V(x, t) = L\Delta x\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}(x, t) + \frac{1}{C \Delta x}\int{I_c(x, t) \; dt} \tag{1}
$$
$$
V(x + \Delta x, t) =\frac{1}{C \Delta x} \int {I_c(x, t) \; dt} \tag{2}
$$
$$
I(x) = I_c + I(x + \Delta x) \tag{3}
$$
This are the equations that describe the circuit once applied Kirchhoff Laws. Using equations 1 and 2:
$$
0 = L\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}(x, t)  + \frac{V(x + \Delta x, t) - V(x, t)}{\Delta x} \\
$$
$$
\boxed{
L\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}  + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = 0 
}\tag 4
$$
Now using equations 3:
$$
I(x) = I_c + I(x + \Delta x) \Rightarrow I(x + \Delta x) - I(x) = -I_c \\
I_c = C \Delta x \frac{\partial V_c}{dt} \\
$$
$$
\boxed { C \frac{\partial V_c}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = 0 } \tag 5
$$
It would be nice if the $V_c = V$, because the equations would be "simetric". Let's try to proof that $V_c = V$:
$$
V(x + \Delta x) = V(x) + \Delta x \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{C \Delta x}\int { I_c \; dt} \\
I_c = C \Delta x \frac{\partial V_c}{\partial t} \\
V(x) + \Delta x \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = V_c \\
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \left [ V(x) + \Delta x \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \right] = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} V_c \\
$$
$$
\boxed{V(x, t) = V_c(x, t)}
$$
Hence we have the simetry we wanted. Now, playing a little bit with equations 4 and 5 we get:
$$
L \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left ( \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} \right) = 0 \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{C}\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} \\
L \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left ( -\frac{1}{C}\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} \right) = 0 \\ 
$$
We get the following wave equation (same happends for $V$):
$$
\boxed{
LC \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial x^2} \\ \; \\ \;
LC \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}
}
$$
With a propagation speed of:
$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}
$$
Is this line of reasoning correct? Is there any step I skipped or something I've had not taken into account? Sorry if the derivation is a bit caotic, hope it's understandable.

Comment: From your diagram $V(x+dx)=V_c$